Unable to detect Python kernels in VS Code Jupyter notebooks after migrating from Windows 11 to Arch Linux
Environment Details

Previous OS: Windows 11
Current OS: Arch Linux
Desktop Environment: KDE Plasma
IDE: Visual Studio Code (OSS CODE)
Required Feature: Jupyter Notebook support

Issue Description
After migrating from Windows 11 to Arch Linux, I'm unable to get Jupyter notebooks working in VS Code. Specifically, VS Code cannot detect any Python kernels for the notebooks, preventing me from running any code.
What I've Tried
Attempt 1: Direct Installation
First, I attempted to install Jupyter directly using pip:
pip install jupyter --break-system-packages

This resulted in an error about externally managed environment, which is expected behavior in Arch Linux.
Attempt 2: Virtual Environment Setup
Then I tried setting up a virtual environment:
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install jupyter

This is the result I got:
[harshal@quanta ~]$ python -m venv .venv
[harshal@quanta ~]$ source .venv/bin/ativate
bash: .venv/bin/ativate: No such file or directory
[harshal@quanta ~]$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  sof-bin  Templates  Videos  yay
[harshal@quanta ~]$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) [harshal@quanta ~]$ code .
(.venv) [harshal@quanta ~]$ 

Code :

Attempt 3: System Package Installation
I also attempted to install through pacman:
sudo pacman -S python-jupyter

This failed with "target not found: python-jupyter" error.
Output of ls -al .venv
drwxr-xr-x  7 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 18:57 .
drwx------ 22 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 21 08:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 18:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 18:57 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 17:33 include
drwxr-xr-x  3 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 17:33 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 harshal harshal    3 Dec 20 17:33 lib64 -> lib
-rw-r--r--  1 harshal harshal  157 Dec 20 18:54 pyvenv.cfg
drwxr-xr-x  6 harshal harshal 4096 Dec 20 18:57 share
[harshal@quanta ~]$

Current State
Even after these attempts, VS Code still cannot detect any Python kernels for Jupyter notebooks, as shown in the screenshot below:

System Configuration

VS Code has the Python extension installed
Python is installed and accessible from terminal
Virtual environment is created but not being detected by VS Code

Expected Behavior
VS Code should be able to:

Detect the Python interpreter in the virtual environment
List it as an available kernel for Jupyter notebooks
Allow running notebook cells using the selected kernel

Actual Behavior

No kernels are being detected
Cannot run any notebook cells
Kernel picker shows no available kernels

Question
How can I properly configure VS Code to detect and use Python kernels for Jupyter notebooks on a fresh Arch Linux installation, considering the system package management restrictions?

What happened with attempt 2? How did that fail? When you open VScode, are you running it from within a shell session with the venv enabled? Can you try that? (open a terminal, run . .venv/bin/activate and then code). Update your question with the result.

If you want to give attempt 3 another try: https://archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=Jupyter&maintainer=&flagged=

@terdon Sir, updated the question

What is the output of ls -al .venv in your home directory

@eyoung100 I can see the .venv directory in my home , but why isn't my code able to identify it i don't have any idea

I don't think there's a package, have you read https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Jupyter? Arch is not a newbie-friendly distribution, it really isn't a good starting place for your first Linux, but it does have one of the best collection of documentation out there. Always check Arch wiki.
